# Flask form in Bootstrap input-group is wrapping to next line on mobile

Tags: html, css, flask, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like the 'Go' button to stay next to the search field. On Desktop view it looks fine but when I switch to a mobile view it wraps the submit button (the input-group gets broken up). how do I prevent that?

Also, bootstrap is adding gray lines around the form when in mobile, if anyone knows how to prevent that I'd live to know.

I tried 'flex-nowrap' from the docs but it's for a different version of Bootstrap, I think. It didn't work.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#wrapping

```
    <body>
    {% block navbar %} <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 16px;" class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">My Website</a>
          
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        
        {% if base['search_bar'] %}
        <div class="navbar-form navbar-left col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
            {{ base['search_bar'].hidden_tag() }}
            {{ base['search_bar'].search_for(class="form-control", placeholder="Search with Barcode") }}
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            {{ base['search_bar'].start_search(class="btn btn-primary") }}
            </span>
          </form>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        {% endif %}

        <div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Register</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ current_user.username }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    {% endblock %} <!-- Nav Bar -->
```

```
class SearchBar(FlaskForm):
    search_for = StringField('Search', validators=[DataRequired()])
    start_search = SubmitField('Go')
```

[This is how it looks for mobile users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBbQS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically place them in the same `.input-group` div. You can use bootstrap's 3 markup syntax.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  {% block navbar %}
  <!-- Nav Bar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 16px;" class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">My Website</a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      </div>

      {% if base['search_bar'] %}
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-left col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
            <div class="input-group">

              <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search with Barcode">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
      {% endif %}

      <div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('signup') }}">Register</a></li>
          {% else %}
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ current_user.username }}</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```